# Access Denied from Migrated SP2010 -> 2013 Web App

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I've migrated a web application's content database from SP2010 to SP2013. After the migration was complete, I am completely locked out of the web application. Navigating to the root site collection prompts me for credentials which are refused every time. The user I'm trying to log in as is a farm administrator as well as site collection administrator.

I've tried using PowerShell to get myself access (this is also part of the migration procedure):

```
$account = "yourDomain\yourUser"
$account = (New-SPClaimsPrincipal -identity $account -identitytype 1).ToEncodedString()
$wa = get-SPWebApplication $WebAppName
$zp = $wa.ZonePolicies("Default")
$p = $zp.Add($account,"PSPolicy")
$fc=$wa.PolicyRoles.GetSpecialRole("FullControl")
$p.PolicyRoleBindings.Add($fc)
$wa.Update() 

$wa.MigrateUsers($true)
$wa.ProvisionGlobally()
```

This hasn't worked. I've also checked the site collection admin in Application Mangement -> Site Collections -> Change site collection administrators

That needed to be changed when it was first switched over as the previous environment was on a different domain, but the user now listed as a site collection admin cannot get to the root site collection.

I've also tried enabling anonymous access in the [process outlined here](http://www.dmcinfo.com/latest-thinking/blog/articletype/articleview/articleid/8565/sharepoint-2013-access-denied-to-root-site-of-web-application.aspx) and still can't get in.

This is just a personal testing environment so no worries about trying anything that breaks, I can always revert the VM.

How can I regain access to this web application?

EDIT: I've also verified/set the portalsuperuseraccount and portalsuperreaderaccount... outlined here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14073/access-denied-on-site-collection-after-migrating-to-claims

Comment: What authentication methods are you using on the 2010 and the respective 2013 site?

Comment: @Paul 2010 was classic, migrated to 2013 as classic, and upgraded to claims once it was attached to a 2013 classic auth web app.

Comment: as far as i remember it was recommended to upgrade to claims before the migration, have you tried it this way?

Comment: @Paul I found this out a little ways into the migration. No, I have not tried that but I very easily can. I'm going to snapshot both environments and give that a try.

Comment: also did you attach the content-database using `Mount-SPContentDatabase` or with the stsadm tool.
In my test migration the mount-spcontentdatabase cmdlet did not work for me while stsadm -addcontentdb did the job.

Comment: @Paul I did use Mount-SPContentDatabase. Thats strange, what do you mean by "did not work"?

Comment: if i recall correctly the upgrade process failed when i used the cmdlet, even if test-spcontentdatabase did not give any errors